# Facebook changed the default email address for every contact.  How do I mitigate the impact and risk?

Tags: mobile, email, privacy, compliance, corporate-policy

Facebook [created a problem](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/07/02/facebook_contact_push/) for regulated industries and [Registered Investment Advisers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_Investment_Advisor) (RIAs) by changing the default outgoing SMTP address for every contact to a `@Facebook.com` address.

This is an issue because RIAs are subject to external compliance auditing, usually though a 3rd party journaling target such as SMARSH or Proofpoint Archive.

For example, suppose an email addresses changes to `@facebook.com`, then that means all email protections that were in place by the company (such as [encryption](http://www.zixcorp.com/products/zixmail/), AV, etc.) also bypasses the required any other journaling infrastructure that is required by law.

**Questions**

- What are the exact circumstances that cause the default email address to change?
- If the email address has changed, how does that affect liability?
- If the email address changed on the mobile device, does it also change Outlook's default address (Exchange Server/OWA presumably as well)?
- Does the scope of the SEC search or legal search now expand to a Facebook address as a result?  (affecting privacy)
- How does one mitigate the risk, and/or undo the changes?

Comment: 100%. Agreed with Ramhound's answer. The problem with them is that they want to you stop using your own address. Recovery e-mail didn't work as an account recovery option anyway since a very long time ago. Practically, they want you fully assimilated.

Answer (score 3):

```
What are the exact circumstances that cause the default email address to change?
```

Facebook wants control.

```
If the email address has changed, how does that affect liability?
```

Just change it back?

```
How does one mitigate the risk, and/or undo the changes?
```

You change it, like you have always been able to do, Facebook even has a support article on the subject.